# Private registry not working properly after deleting an image

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have the problem that my registry stops working correctly after I delete an image from it. I want to delete images from the private registry to free some storage space and clean unused images.

**I have the following setup / workflow:**

1. My private registry with my own self-signed SSL certificate
2. I Build an image and push it to the registry
3. I pull the image on another host
4. I delete the image from the registry from the registry using the API
5. I call the registrys garbage collector
6. I try to pull the image from the registry
7. I try to push the image (not changed) to the registry again
8. I try to pull the image on the other host again

Steps 1 - 6 are working fine, step 4 is kinda working (i guess) but steps 7 - 8 are not working as expected.

**Expected results:**

4. Image is completely removed from the registry
5. I push the image to the registry during this process some layers (which I deleted in step 4) get pushed.
6. I can pull the image again

**Actual results:**

4. The image is still present in the registry but has no tags. It seems like this is the way the registry handles image deletion...
5. I can push the image but it says 'Layer already exists' for every layer
6. I cant pull the image anymore, docker says: `Error response from daemon: manifest for registry.swarm/waterfall:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`

**Notes:**

- After step 8 failed, checking the registry shows me that my image has a tag called "latest" but I cant retrieve the manifest for it using the API (basically the same error as 'docker pull' returned)
- Pushing the image won't solve the problem.

**Workaround:**

The only way to fix the image in the registry is rebuilding the image on the host and pushing the new version.

**Second case:**

If I skip step 5 the pull in step 8 kinda works. It starts to pull the image but at some layer docker fails and says "retrying in x seconds". After a few minutes docker managed to pull the whole image. but fails with `EOF` (nothing more)

Is this the intended behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an old unresolved caching issue of the distribution registry (check here the [link](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/2094) to the open issue).

I have configured my private repository to use `inmemory` `blobdescriptor` caching and experienced the same issue as you did (see the config section below).

```yaml
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
  level: info
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: inmemory
  filesystem:
...
```

The only easy fix for such a configuration would be to restart the private docker registry.

Assuming you have deployed the private registry as a docker container, simply run:

```sh
docker restart <your_registry_container>
```

The official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#cache) mentions only two types of cache `blobdescriptor` configuration: `inmemory` and `redis`.

But apparently, setting the `blobldescriptor` value to be `""` does the trick of disabling caching.

```yaml
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
  level: info
storage:
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: ""
  filesystem:
...
```

And you don't have to restart the registry, anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the solution.